# Изменение параметра при пересечении курсором границы формы

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, ХешКод, как сделать так, что пока курсор на форме, то параметр

```
this.Opacity = 100;
```

Как только курсор покидает форму параметр изменяется на

```
this.Opacity = 30;
```

Comment: Посмотрите события Leave, MouseLeave или LostFocus именно для формы, к сожалению, нет возможности проверить самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1):

Для C# WinForms события MouseEnter и MouseLeave:

```
private void Form1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Opacity = 1;
    }

private void Form1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Opacity = 0.3;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

То, что вам предложили с `MouseEnter / MouseLeave` - это *плохое решение.* Если у вас на форме есть контролы, то в случае этого решения может возникнуть такая ситуация:

```
+---------------------------------+ 
|     [Inner Control]             |
+---------------------------------+

Parent.OnMouseEnter      (1.0)
Parent.OnMouseLeave      (0.3)
Inner.OnMouseEnter       (1.0)
Inner.OnMouseLeave       (0.3)
Parent.OnMouseEnter      (1.0)
Parent.OnMouseLeave      (0.3)
```

---

Хорошее решение подразумевает вставку **фиктивной панели** *(и проверку выхода за ее границы)* или `MouseEnter / MouseLeave` с [**фильтрацией сообщений.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx)